# Is it a good (correct) way to encapsulate a collection?

Tags: c++, collections, encapsulation

```
class MyContainedClass {
};

class MyClass {
public:
  MyContainedClass * getElement() {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return &(*it);
  }
  // other methods
private:
  std::list<MyContainedClass> m_contained;
};
```

Though msdn says `std::list` should not perform relocations of elements on deletion or insertion, is it a good and common way to return pointer to a list element?

PS: I know that I can use collection of pointers (and will have to `delete` elements in destructor), collection of shared pointers (which I don't like), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the use of encapsulating this, but that may be just me. In any case, returning a reference instead of a pointer makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

In a general sort of way, if your "contained class" is truly contained in your "MyClass", then MyClass should not be allowing outsiders to touch its private contents.

So, MyClass should be providing methods to manipulate the contained class objects, not returning pointers to them.  So, for example, a method such as "increment the value of the umpteenth contained object", rather than "here is a pointer to the umpteenth contained object, do with it as you wish".

Answer (score 1):

### It depends...

It depends on how much encapsulated you want your class to be, and what you want to hide, or show.

The code I see seems ok for me. You're right about the fact the std::list's data and iterators won't be invalidated in case of another data/iterator's modification/deletion.

Now, returning the pointer would hide the fact you're using a std::list as an internal container, and would not let the user to navigate its list. Returning the iterator would let more freedom to navigate this list for the users of the class, but they would "know" they are accessing a STL container.

It's your choice, there, I guess.

Note that if it == std::list<>.end(), then you'll have a problem with this code, but I guess you already know that, and that this is not the subject of this discussion.

Still, there are alternative I summarize below:

### Using `const` will help...

The fact you return a non-const pointer lets the user of you object silently modify any MyContainedClass he/she can get his/her hands on, without telling your object.

Instead or returning a pointer, you could return a const pointer (and suffix your method with const) to stop the user from modifying the data inside the list without using an accessor approved by you (a kind of `setElement` ?).

```
  const MyContainedClass * getElement() const {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return &(*it);
  }
```

This will increase somewhat the encapsulation.

### What about a reference?

If your method cannot fail (i.e. it always return a valid pointer), then you should consider returning the reference instead of the pointer. Something like:

```
  const MyContainedClass & getElement() const {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return *it;
  }
```

This has nothing to do with encapsulation, though..
:-p

### Using an iterator?

Why not return the iterator instead of the pointer? If for you, navigating the list up and down is ok, then the iterator would be better than the pointer, and is used mostly the same way.

Make the iterator a const_iterator if you want to avoid the user modifying the data.

```
  std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator getElement() const {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return it;
  }
```

The good side would be that the user would be able to navigate the list. The bad side is that the user would know it is a std::list, so...

Answer (score 1):

Scott Meyers in his book [Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) says it's just not worth trying to encapsulate your containers since none of them are completely replaceable for another.

Answer (score 1):

Think *good and hard* about what you really want `MyClass` for. I've noticed that some programmers write wrappers for their collections just as a matter of habit, regardless of whether they have any specific needs above and beyond those met by the standard STL collections. If that's your situation, then `typedef std::list<MyContainedClass> MyClass` and be done with it.

If you *do* have operations you intend to implement in `MyClass`, then the success of your encapsulation will depend more on the interface you provide for them than on how you provide access to the underlying list.

No offense meant, but... With the limited information you've provided, it *smells* like you're punting: exposing internal data because you can't figure out how to implement the operations your client code requires in `MyClass`... or possibly, because you don't even *know* yet what operations will be required by your client code. This is a classic problem with trying to write low-level code before the high-level code that requires it; you know what data you'll be working with, but haven't really nailed down exactly what you'll be doing with it yet, so you write a class structure that exposes the raw data all the way to the top. You'd do well to re-think your strategy here.

---

[@cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108389/is-it-a-good-correct-way-to-encapsulate-a-collection#113052):

> Of course I'm encapsulating
>   MyContainedClass not just for the sake
>   of encapsulation. Let's take more
>   specific example:

Your example does little to allay my fear that you are writing your containers before you know what they'll be used for. Your example container wrapper - `Document` - has a total of three methods: `NewParagraph()`, `DeleteParagraph()`, and `GetParagraph()`, all of which operate on the contained collection (`std::list`), *and all of which* closely mirror operations that `std::list` provides "out of the box". `Document` encapsulates std::list in the sense that clients need not be aware of its use in the implementation... but realistically, it is little more than a facade - since you are providing clients raw pointers to the objects stored in the list, the client is still tied implicitly to the implementation.

> If we put objects (not pointers) to
>   container they will be destroyed
>   automatically (which is good).

Good or bad depends on the needs of your system. What this implementation means is simple: the document owns the `Paragraph`s, and when a `Paragraph` is removed from the document any pointers to it immediately become invalid. Which means you must be *very* careful when implementing something like:

> other objects than use collections of
>   paragraphs, but don't own them.

Now you have a problem. Your object, `ParagraphSelectionDialog`, has a list of pointers to `Paragraph` objects owned by the `Document`. If you are not careful to coordinate these two objects, the `Document` - or another client by way of the `Document` - could invalidate some or all of the pointers held by an instance of `ParagraphSelectionDialog`! There's no easy way to catch this - a pointer to a valid `Paragraph` looks the same as a pointer to a deallocated `Paragraph`, and may even end up pointing to a valid - but different - `Paragraph` instance! Since clients are allowed, and even expected, to retain and dereference these pointers, the `Document` loses control over them as soon as they are returned from a public method, even while it retains ownership of the `Paragraph` objects.

This... is bad. You've end up with an incomplete, superficial, encapsulation, a leaky abstraction, and in some ways it is worse than having no abstraction at all. Because you hide the implementation, your clients have no idea of the lifetime of the objects pointed to by your interface. You would probably get lucky most of the time, since most `std::list` operations do not invalidate references to items they don't modify. And all would be well... until the wrong `Paragraph` gets deleted, and you find yourself stuck with the task of tracing through the callstack looking for the client that kept that pointer around a little bit too long.

The fix is simple enough: return values or objects that can be stored for as long as they need to be, and verified prior to use. That could be something as simple as an ordinal or ID value that must be passed to the `Document` in exchange for a usable reference, or as complex as a reference-counted smart pointer or weak pointer... it really depends on the specific needs of your clients. Spec out the client code first, then write your `Document` to serve.

Comment: thank you for comments. I'll have to think about this. Anyway I write "// other properties" in Document which mean that it has other fields which store it's specific values, for ex. page color, page size etc.

Answer (score 1):

**The Easy way**

@cos, For the example you have shown, i would say the easiest way to create this system in C++ would be to not trouble with the reference counting. All you have to do would be to make sure that the program flow first destroys the objects (views) which holds the  direct references to the objects (paragraphs) in the collection, before the root Document get destroyed.

**The Tough Way**

However if you still want to control the lifetimes by reference tracking, you might have to hold references deeper into the hierarchy such that Paragraph objects holds reverse references to the root Document object such that, only when the last paragraph object gets destroyed will the Document object get destructed.

Additionally the paragraph references when used inside the Views class and when passed to other classes, would also have to passed around as reference counted interfaces.

**Toughness**

This is too much overhead, compared to the simple scheme i listed in the beginning. It avoids all kinds of object counting overheads and more importantly someone who inherits your program does not get trapped in the reference dependency threads traps that criss cross your system.

**Alternative Platforms**

This kind-of tooling might be easier to perform in a platform that supports and promotes this style of programming like .NET or Java.

**You still have to worry about memory**

Even with a platform such as this you would still have to ensure your objects get de-referenced in a proper manner. Else outstanding references could eat up your memory in the blink of an eye. So you see, reference counting is not the panacea to good programming practices, though it helps avoid lots of error checks and cleanups, which when applied the whole system considerably eases the programmers task.

**Recommendation**

That said, coming back to your original question which gave raise to all the reference counting doubts - Is it ok to expose your objects directly from the collection?

Programs cannot exist where all classes / all parts of the program are truly interdependent of each other. No, that would be impossible, as a program is the running manifestation of how your classes / modules interact. The ideal design can only minimize the dependencies and not remove them totally.

So my opinion would be, *yes it is not a bad practice to expose the references to the objects from your collection, to other objects that need to work with them, provided you do this in a sane manner*

1. Ensure that only a few classes / parts of your program can get such references to ensure minimum interdependency.
2. Ensure that the references / pointers passed are interfaces and not concrete objects so that the interdependency is avoided between concrete classes.
3. Ensure that the references are not further passed along deeper into the program.
4. Ensure that the program logic takes care of destroying the dependent objects, before cleaning up the actual objects that satisfy those references.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger problem is that you're hiding the type of collection so even if you use a collection that doesn't move elements you may change your mind in the future. Externally that's not visible so I'd say it's not a good idea to do this.

Comment: I thought that hiding the actual method of object storage and organization is the main goal of encaplusation (and for ex. I can change list storage to database access and other external objects wouldn't feel the difference)

Comment: What would then encapsulate the class you have newly created? 

My point being that the encapsulation you are trying to achieve, of encapsulating the collection which is already encasulated by STL is akin to what i have asked.

Answer (score 0):

std::list will not invalidate any iterators, pointers or references when you add or remove things from the list (apart from any that point the item being removed, obviously), so using a list in this way isn't going to break.

As others have pointed out, you may want not want to be handing out direct access to the private bits of this class. So changing the function to:

```
  const MyContainedClass * getElement() const {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return &(*it);
  }
```

may be better, or if you always return a valid MyContainedClass object then you could use

```
    const MyContainedClass& getElement() const {
    // ...
    std::list<MyContainedClass>::const_iterator it = ... // retrieve somehow
    return *it;
  }
```

to avoid the calling code having to cope with NULL pointers.

Answer (score 0):

STL will be more familiar to a future programmer than your custom encapsulation, so you should avoid doing this if you can. There will be edge cases that you havent thought about which will come up later in the app's lifetime, wheras STL is failry well reviewed and documented.

Additionally most containers support somewhat similar operations like begin end push etc. So it should be fairly trivial to change the container type in your code should you change the container. eg vector to deque or map to hash_map etc.

Assuming you still want to do this for a more deeper reason, i would say the correct way to do this is to implement all the methods and iterator classes that list implements. Forward the calls to the member list calls when you need no changes. Modify and forward or do some custom actions where you need to do something special (the reason why you decide to this in the first place)

It would be easier if STl classes where designed to be inherited from but for efficiency sake it was decided not to do so. Google for "inherit from STL classes" for more thoughts on this.